# Call a function within a second function to pass the output into the second function

Tags: python

I have another function for Pre-processing the text called "CleanText" and I want to call the "CleanText" function within the function below to pass the output into

This is my first Function

```
def CleanText(doc) :
with open(doc, "r") as myfile:
    corpus = myfile.read()
    docs = corpus.splitlines()
doc_tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(x) for x in docs] 
doc_tokens_no_punc = [remove_punc(a_doc) for a_doc in doc_tokens]
doc_tokens_no_punc_lower = [[element.lower() for element in x] for x in doc_tokens_no_punc]
doc_tokens_clean = [[x.lower() for x in words if x.lower() not in stop] for words in doc_tokens_no_punc_lower]
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
doc_tokens_clean_stem = [token for sublist in [[stemmer.stem(y) for y in x] for x in doc_tokens_clean] for token in sublist]
return doc_tokens_clean_stem
```

This is my second function

```
def buildDocWordMatrix(doclist) :
    wordlist = []
    for doc in x :
        for word in doc:
            if(not(word in wordlist)):
                wordlist.append(word)
    docword= []
    for m in x:
        doc_vec = [0]*len(wordlist)
        for word in m:
            ind = wordlist.index(word)
            doc_vec[ind] += 1
            docword.append(doc_vec)
    return docword, wordlist
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. `def` should have less indentation than the rest of the code. And `return` shouldn't be inside the loop.

Comment: Where do you want to call `CleanText()`?

Comment: Maybe something like `return CleanText(docword), wordlist)`?

Comment: i have added my first function, i want to use the output of the 1st function in the for loop for Wordlist and for docword list

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the function. Why is it so hard to do that when you're posting the question?

Comment: @Barmar, When i have assigned the first function to a variable, I got this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'doc' referenced before assignment"

Comment: What is `x` in `for doc in x:`? Shouldn't that be `for doc in doclist:`?

Comment: Maybe something like `for word in CleanText(doc):` is what you want?

Comment: That was the variable for the first function it was like x = cleanText(doclist)

Comment: @Barmar i tried that before but i got this error "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop should process `doclist`, there is no variable `x`.

The inner loop should process the result of `CleanText(doc)`

```
def buildDocWordMatrix(doclist) :
    wordlist = []
    for doc in doclist:
        for phrase in CleanText(doc):
            for word in phrase:
                if(not(word in wordlist)):
                    wordlist.append(word)
    docword= []
    for m in x:
        doc_vec = [0]*len(wordlist)
        for word in m:
            ind = wordlist.index(word)
            doc_vec[ind] += 1
            docword.append(doc_vec)
    return docword, wordlist
```

Comment: i got error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"

Comment: Either fix `CleanText()` to return a list of words you can loop over, or add another level of looping here to process the nested lists.